# Google Docs API fetch ACL with batch operation

Tags: objective-c, gdata-api, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm developing an iPhone app than uses the Google apps API.

I'm fetching all the documents in Google Docs and want to fetch the ACL for each document. I can do this by calling:

```
[service fetchFeedWithURL:entry.ACLFeedLink.URL completionHandler:^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataFeedBase *ACLFeed, NSError *error){            
}];
```

But because I want to have the ACL for each document, this will require a lot of requests. Can I do it using a batch operation instead?

I have tried the following:

```
GDataFeedBase *batchFeed = [[GDataFeedBase alloc] init];
NSURL *batchUrl = [[feed batchLink] URL];

GDataBatchOperation *batchOperation = [GDataBatchOperation batchOperationWithType:kGDataBatchOperationQuery];
[batchFeed setBatchOperation:batchOperation];

GDataEntryBase *entryACL = [[GDataEntryBase alloc] init];
[entryACL setIdentifier:[[[[feed entries] objectAtIndex:0] ACLFeedLink] href]];
[batchFeed addEntryWithEntry:entryACL];

[service fetchFeedWithBatchFeed:batchFeed forBatchFeedURL:batchUrl completionHandler:^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataFeedBase *feed, NSError *error){
}];
```

But it doenst work. I only get the actual documents and not the ACL feed.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACL batching can only be performed for multiple ACLs on a single resource, so this will not help you.

An approach which will be more useful for fetching ACLs would be to use the `expand-acl` query parameter on a GET, e.g.:

```
GET https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/?v=3&expand-acl=true
```